# Monitor Kafka using Opensource tools

Tags: apache-kafka

Any Opensource tool to monitor confluent Kafka? Most of the opensource tools available are specific to Apache Kafka but not for Confluent Kafka.

we want to monitor atleast the connectors, streams and cluster health

Answer (score 3):

The Kafka that is distributed in the Confluent Platform *is* Apache Kafka. There really is no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". Any tools that work with the latest version of Apache Kafka (including Kafka Connect and Kafka Streams) will work with the same versions of Kafka included with Confluent Open Source.

Confluent 3.3 includes Apache Kafka 0.11
Confluent 3.2 includes Apache Kafka 0.10.2
Confluent 3.1 includes Apache Kafka 0.10.1
Confluent 3.0 includes Apache Kafka 0.10.0
Confluent 2.0 includes Apache Kafka 0.9
Confluent 1.0 includes Apache Kafka 0.8.2

Note: Confluent Enterprise includes its own monitoring and management GUI called Control Center. Control Center is a separate process so the Apache Kafka is still the same as the open source version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use updated version of [KafkaOffsetMonitor](https://github.com/dmilan77/kafka-offset-monitor). It supports SSL/TLS and Kerbros. Also uses Kafka 1.1.0 library.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [kafka-monitor](https://github.com/linkedin/kafka-monitor) for monitoring your cluster's health as well as [Burrow](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/collecting-kafka-performance-metrics/#monitoring-consumer-health-with-burrow) and [KafkaOffsetMonitor](https://www.quantifind.com/kafkaoffsetmonitor) for monitoring your consumer application lag. Also, you should definitely use something like [jmxtrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans) for collecting your Kafka broker metrics.